# Как из ответа на запрос вытащить число и подставить в другой запрос?

Tags: jmeter

Есть sql запрос, после его исполнения в ответ приходит таблица с данными, есть столбец excess, в нем числа, как 8 значные, так и 10 значные, а могут вообще отсутствовать.
При отправке запроса с лимитом 1, возвращается ответ с 1 строкой, в столбце excess может быть пусто, а может быть 8 значное число, или 10 значное.

Как вытаскивать данные (для параметризации ими следующего запроса) при исполнении каждого запроса, даже если там пусто, или число любого размера?

[image: Скрин столбца с данными]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Укажите переменную JMeter в которую будет записан результат в [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после выполнения запроса появятся следующие переменные:

- `${excess_1}` - значение для первого ряда (если вы используете [LIMIT 1](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_limit.asp)) то будет только одна переменная
- `${excess_2}` - значение для второго ряда
- `${excess_#}` - количество возвращенных SQL запросов рядов из таблицы

Пример параметризации запросов используя данные из базы: [How to Retrieve Database Data for API Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter)